# workspace does not return the correct value for me

Tags: smalltalk

i have problem with some code.

If i write  `Recenzes select: [:a | a komponenta nazev = 'Hitachi P21']` i got some right records. But if i use something like this:

```
| brzdy |
brzdy := (((
   (Sekces select: [:b | b nazev = 'Brzdy']) collect: [:b | b komponenty]) flatten)
       select: [:c | c vyrobce nazev = 'Hitachi']) collect: [:d | d nazev].
```

i can get 'Hitachi P21' with ^ command. But if i use variable 'brzdy' here: `Recenzes select: [:a | a komponenta nazev = brzdy]` i won't get anything.

In a nutshell. I want to show 'Recenzes' for 'Komponenty' which are in 'Sekces' with value 'Brzdy' and they are saved in column 'Komponenty' (Set) for 'Recenzes' and 'Sekces'.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Leandro seems to have answered the question but I'll note a couple suggestions:  While it is completely legal to put everything on one line, it does make it hard to debug these sort of questions. If you put it on a series of separate lines then you could narrow down which transformation is misbehaving. You could step through the code with breakpoints or output intermediate values to the console. Also, could you mention which dialect and version of Smalltalk you have? In any case, welcome to the Smalltalk community!

Comment: I use Czech dialect if u mean this. I have Smalltalk 7.4. About all in one line. That is my bad formating. Ty

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about dialect! Smalltalk is a "language" and there are many different implementations of it. Each implementation is a "dialect" (not a new language, but sufficiently different that the vocabulary or idioms might be unfamiliar). So, Pharo, VisualWorks, Squeak, VA, GemStone, Dolphin, Smalltalk X, and others are each their own "dialect" (much as Swiss German is different from Deutsch German). When answering questions it is helpful to know what "dialect" of Smalltalk you have. I'm more familiar with some than with others!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `brzdy` is the result of a `#collect:` message, it is a collection of strings, not a single string. Therefore no element `a` would satisfy the condition `a komponenta nazev = brzdy`, because you would be comparing objects of different classes. Try something on the lines of

```
Recenzes select: [:a | brzdy includes: a komponenta nazev]
```

---

As a side note, remember that you may eliminate some parentheses by using `select:thenCollect:` other than `(select: blah) collect: bluh`. For instance

```
brzdy := (Sekces select: [:b | b nazev = 'Brzdy'] thenCollect: [:b | b komponenty]) flatten
        select: [:c | c vyrobce nazev = 'Hitachi']
        thenCollect: [:d | d nazev]
```

(I'm not familiar with the `#flatten` message, so I can't tell whether it is necessary or superfluous).

Comment: Ohh, thank you! It works. I use #flatten to create records from Set.